# How to send Mail to Active Directory users in XPages?

Tags: email, active-directory, xpages

First of all, I am not sure if this question is a Stackoverflow or Server Fault question so I ask it here.

I have set up Domino with login as Active Directory using SAML 2.0.

Users can access a webpage and login in using their AD information because I added the AD users to the ACL

There is no users in domino directory.

In my XPage I use @UserName() to display the logged in AD user and it is returning the híerarchial AD name nicely

My question is now how can I access and email Active Directory users in my webpage using XPages. Do these users also need to be in DD for addressing and mail routing to work?

Comment: I authenticate users in Active Directory using LDAP via the use of the directory assistance database. With this approach email to the AD user name works. So maybe try setting up directory assistance against AD?

Comment: I already use directory assistance for login. But when I send a mail to an ad user it doesn’t route

Comment: But does it add the mail to mail.box with the correct email adress?

Comment: I belive it adds to Mail.box using the hierarchial ad name as Mail adress